# I am able to run the container in docker but unable to view in the browser

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, containers

I am new to Docker. Firstly, I have created Dockerfile with in source code location.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8000
```

lately, build an image using: docker build -t mywebapp:v1 .

and i have run the container using following command:

```sh
 docker run -d -p 8000:8000 mywebapp:v1
```

problem is : container is running using port 8000, but unable to view in the browser

http://192.168.13.135:8000

please help me out in this problem inorder to view in the browser.

Comment: The Docker Hub `nginx` image has an nginx config that listens on the standard HTTP port 80.  You do not need an `EXPOSE` line in your Dockerfile, but the second number in the `docker run -p` option needs to be 80.

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) There is no nginx configuration in your image, so nginx is only serving its default test page.  It does not know about your `/app` content at all, even though you have copied that into the image.  What is your web app?  Somehow you need to tell nginx how to serve that, but it depends what kind of app it is.